# How to select multiple values from a list block and perform search?

Tags: search

I am a newbie to Drupal.

I have created a block that contains tags of the important topics on my website so how do I insert a search option for the user so that he can select multiple tags from that block and perform the search operation.

Comment: Welcome to the drupal.SE. Please find my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it's a view, you have to do a couple of things after constructing the view.

1. Click on the Filter Criteria as seen in the screenshot below:
   [image: filtre criteria]
2. Click on Expose this filter, Grouped filters and Allow multiple selections in this order (they will only appear if you click in this order). Please see the screenshot below:
   [image: filtre options]

Comment: Oh Thank you so much for this! Really helped a lot.